# Is it possible to use BindingSource.find on multple columns?

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

Is it possible to use BindingSource.find on multple columns?

I have a treeview and a combobox.  The combobox provides the ID that is used to build the treeview.  When I select a node in the tree view I want to display the details/child information for the ID from the combobox and the tag/ID value from the tree Node.

What is the best way to do this? I was trying to use controls bound to a binding source. I want to change the position of the binding source, but I need to search the binding source for the value from the combo as well as the tree node I just selected?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way to do what I was trying to accomplish, but BindingSource.Filter method works great for my scenario.